# How to use 2 for loops in apache pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

How do I use 2 for loops in Apache Pig?

I have input data as below:

```
1  a 3
15 b 4
1  b 2
25 a 5
15 c 3
1  a 3
15 c 2
25 b 4
```

Intermediate Output: For 1 count total no. of a and b, similar for 15 and 25

```
1 a 6
1 b 2
15 b 4
15 c 5
25 a 5
25 b 4
```

Final output: Need for 1 max count

```
1 a 6
15 c 5
25 a 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = load 'test.input' using PigStorage() as (index:int, id:chararray, count:int);
B = GROUP A by (index, id);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE flatten(group), SUM(A.count) as sum;

store C into '/tmp/intermediate';

D = GROUP C by index;

E = FOREACH D {
    ORDERED_C = order C by sum DESC;
    LIMIT_C = LIMIT ORDERED_C 1;
    GENERATE FLATTEN(LIMIT_C);  -- flatten to take out the unnecessary bag
}
store E into '/tmp/final';
```

Comment: Thanks. I have the same problem in Hive. Can you please help me?